# Using two fields with "in" operator in QueryDSL

Tags: java, sql, subquery, querydsl

I have to write this query using QueryDSL:

```
select *
from table
where(field1, field2) in (
    select inner_field_1, inner_field2
    from ...
);
```

However, I don't know how to use two fields (field1 and field2) with an "in" operator in QueryDSL. I have been looking for it in the documentation but I haven't seen any example of two fields.

This is what I have so far:

```
Expression<?>[] projection = {
    table.field1,
    table.field2
};

SQLSubQuery outterQuery= new SQLSubQuery()
    .from(table)
    .where([some expression].in(inneryQuery.list(projection))) // ???
    .groupBy(contentcache1.programId, contentcache1.id);
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Does field1, field2 mean that you want to concatenate the values of each field?

Comment: No, they are two different fields of two different types. For example, I need the pair (A,B) to be contained in the pairs array returned by the innerQuery: [(A,A), (A,B), (A,C), (B,C)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your original query as:

```
select *
from table, (select distinct inner_field_1, inner_field2 from ...) subquery
where field1 = subquery.field1 and field2 = subquery.field2
```

Then you don't have to use the `IN` operator.

Comment: That is really going to perform very badly, compared to the OP's original query, or an equivalent query using an `EXISTS` predicate. Besides, it's wrong. Your `subquery` could produce more than one record...

Comment: I don't understand why it would perform any worse. I don't see either why it is wrong. My sub-query has a `distinct` to prevent multiplying records. In fact my initial impression was that my version might even perform better.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right about the deduplication. I made a mistake, your join predicate will remove duplicates produced from the cartesian product again. Yet, `DISTINCT` performs an additional operation on the two columns to remove duplicates, and it also prevents some more sophisticated SQL transformations in more complex situations. In Oracle, this leads to a [more expensive execution plan than `IN` or `EXISTS` predicates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c6c2/3)

Comment: Thanks Lukas, that's interesting.

Answer (score 11):

You can express it via

```
SQLSubQuery outerQuery = new SQLSubQuery()
    .from(table)
    .where(Expressions.list(column1, column2, ...).in(inneryQuery.list(projection))) 
    .groupBy(contentcache1.programId, contentcache1.id);
```

Comment: Wonderful! I've modified my query, but I like this way to do it. Thank you very much, I'll keep it in mind :)

Comment: In the IN query, lets say I have an input List<X> , X is an object with two properties a, b. How do I pass this list into the IN Query. So Im not doing any inner query here, I have a literal list of objects(Actual values). Does my object need to extend to be a projection compatible ?

Comment: How can one achieve this in QueryDSL 4.x.x ?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually transform your row-value-expression `IN` predicate into an equivalent `EXISTS` predicate, which should probably work with QueryDSL. [Some details are explained in this blog post](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/05/03/sql-query-transformation-fun-predicates-with-row-value-expressions/), which essentially explains how [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) automatically handles such SQL transformations for you, operating directly on the SQL AST, you'd write:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select()
   .from(TABLE)
   .where(row(TABLE.FIELD1, TABLE.FIELD2).in(
       select(INNER_FIELD1, INNER_FIELD_2)
       .from(...)
   ))
```

Your original query:

```
select *
from table
where(field1, field2) in (
    select inner_field_1, inner_field_2
    from ...
);
```

Is equivalent to this one:

```
select *
from table
where exists (
    select 1
    from ...
    where table.field1 = inner_field_1 and table.field2 = inner_field2
)
```

... which I'm sure you can express with QueryDSL (unfortunately, I don't know the API well enough to show the actual query).

#### Note on compatibility

Chances are that your database doesn't support this kind of row value expression predicate anyway, in case of which you're on the safe side with `EXISTS`. At least these databases do support that predicate:

- DB2
- HSQLDB
- MySQL
- Oracle
- Postgres